# Best way to correctly position text in boxplot to stay level with the tick-labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

In the program I'm working on, the ticks of the boxplot are labeled with a name and stuff like mean, std-dev etc. I'd like to insert some text to the left that explains what those values represent.

The problem is, that I cannot position the text such that it always stays level with the tick labels when resizing the plot window.

I use this line to place the text: `pyplot.gcf().text(0.01, 0.1, "Label\nMean\nMedian\nStdDev\nDatapoints")`

Is there a better way to do this?

Example images:

[Large plot window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcyfT.png)

[Small plot window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HdTw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to position the text using [axes coordinates](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html) for example:

```py
ax.text(-0.05, -0.02, 'Label:\nMean:\nMedian:\nStdev:\nDatapoints:', ha='right', va='top', transform=ax.transAxes)
```

Comment: is pyplot.gcf().text() the same as ax.text()? I will try this tomorrow, thanks!

Comment: If you don't have multiple subplots together, then `ax==plt.gca()`. `gcf()` gives the figure, not the ax.  You need to position your text relative to the axes, not relative to the figure.

Comment: I tested your solution and it seems much better but there is still a slight movement while scaling the plot. Can I tweak it or do I just have to live with that?

Comment: [Subpixel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering) movements are normal when working with text. Consider for example a letter 'm' where you want the 3 vertical segments looking the same, which is impossible if the number of pixels between them isn't exactly the same. Similar things happen to other letters and the distance between letters. When scaling, the good looking text will jump from one optimal position to a next one.